# Chrome developer console does not push numbers into array I created

Tags: javascript, arrays, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to push a sequence of numbers into an array in Chrome dev console snippet, where each additional number pushed to the array is +1 of the prior number pushed into the array (like 1,2.3,4..etc).

The `console.log` I'm getting does not show any added numbers into the array.

Please see my code below:

```js
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
  output.push(count);
  count++;

  console.log(output);
}

fizzBuzz();
```

Comment: it works. what is the problem?

Comment: But you called `fizzBuzz()` just once...

Comment: There is a "Tidy" button in the SO code editor, try it. :-)

Comment: Captain, it should console.log an array of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..etc] each time I run the function.  All it does for me is console.log-ing out [1],  no matter how many time I run it in the Chrome dev tool as a snippet.. Is it putting out [1, 2, 3, 4,  ] for you?

Comment: never mind,  I figured out why I wasn't getting the right console.log,   I didn't run the function from the console,  instead I just tried running the snipped over and over with the play (Ctrl+Enter) button.  Ugh!  Duh.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function only once, so you should only element pushed to array, call it more often, or use a loop inside the fizzbuzz.

```js
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
  output.push(count);
  count++;
  //fizzbuzz logic here
  
}
// 10 times figuratively 
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
  fizzBuzz()
}
console.log(output);
```